# Need help installing Biopython

Tags: python-2.7, biopython

Have mac OS 10.6 and  have python verion 2.7 32 bit intalled as 
well as numpy and scipy.
also have xcode version 3.2, Im really confused as to what to do at this point. I download
biopython version 1.59 and tried to run the setup code in python but it wont work. what am i missing?

when i try and run the setup file in idle i get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Cliff/Downloads/biopython-1.58/setup.py", line 379, in <module>
'Bio.PopGen': ['SimCoal/data/*.par'],
File   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line    140, in setup
raise SystemExit, gen_usage(dist.script_name) + "\nerror: %s" % msg
SystemExit: usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
or: setup.py --help-commands
or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

Comment: How does it not work?  Do you get error messages?  What specifically are you doing?

Comment: well i downloaded the zip file and openned it

Comment: What command did you run that failed?  What error messages did you get?

Comment: i tried to run the setup.py command that came in the zip file, should i move the entire zip file to my python file in prog folder?

Comment: and i posted the error message on my initial post

Answer (score 3):

You need to run `python setup.py install` from Terminal.app.  You should be in a bash, tcsh, etc. shell, not in a Python shell.

Comment: No, this cannot be done from xcode, it needs to be done from Terminal.

Comment: ok so i oppened terminal and tried to run python setup.py install but i get an error message/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
dhcp-238-41:~ Cliff$

Comment: should i save biopython in python folder or somehting?

Comment: You need to `cd` to the directory that contains `setup.py`.

Comment: What folder is `setup.py` in?

Answer (score 1):

Just as an probably easier alternative:
Biopython is also available via pip:

```
pip install biopython
```

Or (even better) via bioconda (try it out, it's great):

```
conda install biopython
```

For this just install miniconda (very easy and does NOT require admin rights) from [here](https://conda.io/miniconda.html). and then add the bioconda channel as per [these simple instructions](https://bioconda.github.io/http://).

Strangly these two simple options are missing in the biopython tutorial

Comment: Several years later, I'd recommend mambaforge/mamba over miniconda as it is much faster. https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that you did not supply a command to the install script. The usual command is 'install', so try:

```
python setup.py install
```

In any event, as the error suggests, you can use:

```
python setup.py --help
```

Comment: would i just type that into python shell?

Comment: No, you should type it into the terminal, and I assumed you do so after CDing to the directory containing setup.py (if you do not, you will have to specify the full path).